# How to install CUDA on 18.10 for an Optimus laptop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus, cuda, 18.10

I have a Thinkpad W520 with NVIDIA Quadro 1000M + integrated Intel GPU. I have just made a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.10 on it.

I want to achieve the following:

- working CUDA,
- working external display through DisplayPort/VGA,
- in Optimus mode, if possible (selected that in the BIOS).

### Status before installing anything

I had `nouveau` set up by default. It finds the external monitor through both DisplayPort and VGA (the connectors on the laptop), but it does not work consistently: the external monitor gets switched off after some time.

### What I've done

I tried to install CUDA along with the corresponding NVIDIA driver:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Had a mysterious crash in the middle of compiling the kernel modules, then finished the install after a reboot with `dkpg --configure -a`. In the end, it installed CUDA 9.1.

At this point, the laptop:

- boots in Optimus mode,
- it does not detect external VGA monitor (will need to test HDMI),
- `glxinfo` says that direct rendering is `Yes`,
- the graphics is however not smooth (I see triangle-like artifacts appearing on screen when I move a window, or part of the screen is refreshed),
- after unpacking and compiling some samples from the original 9.1 toolkit installer to verify CUDA, it turned out that CUDA also has problems.

`matrixMul` does not work, see output:

```
Error! Matrix[204798]=0.00000000, ref=3.19999981 error term is > 1.000000E-06
Error! Matrix[204799]=0.00000000, ref=3.19999981 error term is > 1.000000E-06
Result = FAIL
```

Strange enough, `deviceQuery` does work, see output:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "Quadro 1000M"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          9.1 / 9.1
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 1985 MBytes (2081751040 bytes)
MapSMtoCores for SM 2.1 is undefined.  Default to use 64 Cores/SM
MapSMtoCores for SM 2.1 is undefined.  Default to use 64 Cores/SM
  ( 2) Multiprocessors, ( 64) CUDA Cores/MP:     128 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1400 MHz (1.40 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             900 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 131072 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65535), 3D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1536
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            No
  Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      No
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 9.1, CUDA Runtime Version = 9.1, NumDevs = 1
Result = PASS
```

On an older Ubuntu version booting in NVIDIA-only mode selected in BIOS solved most of these problems (even though the battery drained very fast because of the lack of Optimus). However, this time Ubuntu does not boot at all in this mode.

Comment: I have same model, and the 2.1 capability is too low for CUDA 9.1, try 8.0

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen nvidia do not support ubuntu 18.10 as their driver does not work with the new abi 24. You are probably not running with the nvidia driver.

try adding the following two repositories to your sources.list

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /
```

and downgrade xserver-xorg-core and xserver-xorg-video-* and install cuda (which should install cuda-10)

see if that helps.

Cuda is generally backward compatible, so while the 1000m was relatively capable at the time, it's very old by now (8 years if memory serves) and I'm not sure how many things are still supported on it, but it should still run. As for battery, unless you replaced it recently, it's probably beyond end of life, so I wouldn't look at the battery as an indicator.